# Getting info from currently running unit test

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, testcontext

I have to find info about the currently running UnitTest from a helper class' static method.
The Idea is getting a unique key from each test.

I thought about using `TestContext`, not sure if it is possible.

Exemple

```
[TestClass]
public void MyTestClass
{
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTestMethod()
    {
        TestContext.Properties.Add("MyKey", Guid.NewGuid());

        //Continue....
    }
}


public static class Foo
{

    public static Something GetSomething()
    {
        //Get the guid from test context.
        //Return something base on this key
    }

}
```

We are currently storing this key on the thread with `Thread.SetData`, but it is problematic if the tested code spawn multiple thread. For each thread I need to get the same key for a given unit test.

`Foo.GetSomething()` is not called from the unittest itself. The code calling it is a mock injected by Unity.

**Edit**

I'll explain the context a little bit, because it seems to be confusing.

The object created via unity is entity framework's context. When running unit tests, the context get its data in a structure that is created by `Foo.GetSomething`. Let's call it `DataPersistance`.

`DataPersistance` cannot be a singleton, because unit tests would impact each others.

We currently have one instance of `DataPersistance` per thread, witch is nice as long as the tested code is single threaded.

I want one instance of `DataPersistance` per unit test. If a could get an unique guid per test, I could resolve the instance for this test.

Comment: Why don't you just pass it as parameter to the helper class?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Darin: because the helper class is static, and it is called somewhere far far away by an object that is created via Unity.

Comment: Created via Unity? What kind of object is this? I thought it was a helper class specifically created for your unit test? Isn't that the case? I hope that's not an actual class used in your real code under test.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class Foo
{   
    public static Something GetSomething(Guid guid)
    {
        //Return something base on this key
        return new Something();
    } 
}
```

Test:

```
[TestClass]
public void MyTestClass
{
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTestMethod()
    {
        Guid guid = ...;
        Something something = Foo.GetSomething(guid);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Foo.GetSomething` is not called directly from the test method.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Fake your database?

Comment: In a certain way, yes.

Comment: Create a `Repository` and fake your `Repository`.

Comment: Currently we are mocking the context behind the repository - and that's not going to change soon because it works well for 95% of the cases. That said, I doubt I would have the same problem mocking repository.